# Measure small capacitances with ATtiny85 (Digispark board)

Tags: analogread, attiny85, digispark

I have successfully run the code provided [here](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut10_1.php) on an Arduino Nano. If nothing is connected, it will output a very small capacitance (~ 1 pF).

Then I tried to migrate the code to the ATtiny85 (using a Digispark USB Development Board), but I fail to get anything reasonable out of the code. The first `analogRead` will always give 1023, whereas on the Nano it gives a very small value (again for nothing connected to the input pins).

It's a bit trickier on the ATtiny85 because the pin numbers are different for digital and analog, but I thought I got that right, so what went wrong in the migration?

```
const int OUT_PIN = 2; // digital pin PB2 is 2, positive pin of C
const int IN_PIN  = 5; // digital pin PB5 is 5, negative pin of C
const int OUT_ANA = 1; // analog read PB2 is 1
const int IN_ANA  = 0; // analog read PB5 is 0

const float IN_STRAY_CAP_TO_GND = 24.48;
const float IN_CAP_TO_GND  = IN_STRAY_CAP_TO_GND;
const float R_PULLUP = 34.8;  
const int MAX_ADC_VALUE = 1023;

#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

void setup() {
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(OUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN_PIN, LOW);  
  DigiKeyboard.update();
}

void loop() {

    pinMode(IN_PIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, HIGH);
    int val = analogRead(IN_ANA); // IN_PIN in Nano version
    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);

    DigiKeyboard.println(val);
    if (val < 1000) {
      pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
      float capacitance = (float)val * IN_CAP_TO_GND / (float)(MAX_ADC_VALUE - val);
      DigiKeyboard.print(capacitance);
      DigiKeyboard.println(" pF");
    } else {
      pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
      delay(1);
      pinMode(OUT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
      unsigned long u1 = micros();
      unsigned long t;
      int digVal;

      do {
        digVal = digitalRead(OUT_PIN);
        unsigned long u2 = micros();
        t = u2 > u1 ? u2 - u1 : u1 - u2;
      } while ((digVal < 1) && (t < 400000L));

      pinMode(OUT_PIN, INPUT);  
      val = analogRead(OUT_ANA); // OUT_PIN in Nano version
      digitalWrite(IN_PIN, HIGH);
      int dischargeTime = (int)(t / 1000L) * 5;
      delay(dischargeTime);   
      pinMode(OUT_PIN, OUTPUT);  
      digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);
      digitalWrite(IN_PIN, LOW);

      float capacitance = -(float)t / R_PULLUP / log(1.0 - (float)val / (float)MAX_ADC_VALUE);

      if (capacitance > 1000.0) {
        DigiKeyboard.print(capacitance / 1000.0);
        DigiKeyboard.println(" uF");
      } else {
        DigiKeyboard.print(capacitance);
        DigiKeyboard.println(" nF");
      }
      DigiKeyboard.println(val); // usually ~ 520 (because we wait until digVal == 1?)
      DigiKeyboard.println(t); // depends on C: ~ 26000 for 1 µF, ~ 2600 for 100 nF, ~ 250000 for 10 µF
  }

  digitalWrite(1, 1);
  delay(10);
  while (micros() % 1000 != 0);
  digitalWrite(1, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that PB5 is pulled high (as it's used as -RESET pin on the board). The code can be rewritten to use only one ADC pin though.